# How to merge overlapping rectangles in opencv C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to merge overlapping rectangles, represented as `vector<Rect>`

I am looking at the documentation here https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d54/group__objdetect.html for `groupRectangles` but it's not clear what the parameters (what is `eps`?) are.

What is the easiest way to merge rectangles in opencv c++?

An example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `|` union [operator](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html):

> rect = rect1 | rect2 (minimum area rectangle containing rect1 and rect2 )
>
> rect |= rect1 (and the corresponding augmenting operations)

Given a vector of rectangles, the code below creates a single rectangle that contains all the others:

```
std::vector<cv::Rect> rects;
// fill rects....
cv::Rect final = rects[0];
for(const auto& r : rects) { final |= r; }
```

Comment: Never needed this before, and never thought about it, but this is super handy - will definitely remember that!

Answer (score 0):

Eps parameter indicates how much intersection between the rectangle needs to be in order to merge them. For example, a 0.2 eps states that rectangles with more than 20% of overlapped area will be merged.

Comment: Thanks. Could you share an example of the c++ api call, please? The docs don't have any

Comment: `std::vector<cv::Rect> rectangles = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 4, 4]];
cv2.groupRectangles(rectangles,1,0.8)`

Comment: is `rectangles` modified in-place?

Comment: I don't really understand this api. I have a vector `detected` whose size is 7. Now i do:  `groupRectangles(detected, detected.size(), 0);` I expect the size to remain the same as no grouping should be done for the given params. However, it's size changes to 0.

Comment: @nz_21 yes, rectangles vector will be modified in-place.

Comment: @nz_21 _groupThreshold Minimum possible number of rectangles minus 1. The threshold is used in a group of rectangles to retain it._  You are saying that the minimum number of rectangles is 3, therefore it cannot find any solution.

Comment: if I change to `groupRectangles(detected, 1, 0)` its size changes to 0 :(.